# Waiting for service response and then go ahead in angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, http, angular6, angular7

Basically Ι want that when one component is called it should wait till the service returns the data.
I have a component when it loads it calls the one service. In the service I have a function that has the HTTP call, then it gives the response it calls the service another function, so when I simply execute the component, it gives the response too late. I want to wait until the service returns the response data.

I tried with `setTimeout` and promises, but still, it takes the time and function to execute ahead.

Set Timeout

```
setTimeout(() => {
  if (this.persistenceService.get('base64') != '' || this.persistenceService.get('base64') != null || this.persistenceService.get('base64') != undefined) {
    this.selectedFileData = this.persistenceService.get('base64');
    this.SpinnerStart = false;
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectedFileData = this.persistenceService.get('base64');
      this.SpinnerStart = false;
    }, 10000);
  }
}, 10000);
```

I want to load the component loader until the service gives the response.
Here the service code:

````
   this.HttpClients.post(APIcall, Data, config).subscribe(
     async (response: any) => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          this.json_data = response.data;

          this.invoice_pdf(this.json_data, types, '', types, this.Invoice_Number);
          // $template_id
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    );

}```
````

Comment: Can you please share the `service` code to help us understand how data is getting returned from service.

Comment: Instead of subscribing the API call inside service, return an observable and stop the loader as soon as you receive a response.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
selectedFileData$: Observable<FileData>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedFileData$ = this.persistenceService.get('base64'); // Observable!
}

<ng-container *ngIf="selectedFileData$ | async as selectedFileData; else spinner">
  // your business stuff
</ng-container>

<ng-template #spinner>
  // your spinner stuff
<ng-template>
```